# cxGrid clear columns on form close

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe4

I have a grid that I use to display few query results (cxGrid1.ActiveLevel.GridView := cxGrid1DBTableView1; etc ...). On form close, I close the queries as well.

However, the former columns that were last displayed remain visible (when I return to that form again) How can I eliminate these traces of columns as well? I would like empty grid when I return to the form.

Edit : This is the query that I run :

```
procedure TForm2.cxRadioGroup1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
case cxRadioGroup1.ItemIndex of
0: begin
   with Form1.UniQuery3 do begin
   Close;
   sql.Clear;
   sql.Add('select * from program_log');
   Open;
   cxGrid1.ActiveLevel.GridView := cxGrid1DBTableView1;

end;
end;
1: begin
  with Form1.UniQuery4 do begin
   Close;
   sql.Clear;
   sql.Add('select * from guests_log');
   Open;
   cxGrid1.ActiveLevel.GridView := cxGrid1DBTableView2;
end;
end;
end;
end;
```

Calling

```
cxGrid1DBTableView1.ClearItems;
```

Removes all traces of columns which are then unavailable if I want to run the query again.

Comment: 1) Do you mean to say that you re-use the grid for different queries? If so, I understand "the former columns that were last displayed". If not so, how were these columns determined/set - automatic or any specific code from you, or user behaviour. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling **cxGrid1DBTableView1.ClearItems** will remove all columns. Just call it in your FormClose event handler. To recreate columns call **cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.CreateAllItems** function.

Comment: I tought of this too but when I clear the items I clear them for good.That means if I run the query again no column show.

Comment: To recreate all columns based on assigned data source, call **cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.CreateAllItems** function.

Comment: create all items double my column names when I run the query again.

Comment: Are you calling CreateAllItems twice? You can always call **CreateAllItems(True)**. That will create only missing columns.

Comment: yes,CreateAllItems(True) does the trick.But unfortunately it messes one of my fields called "comment". It is memo type and in grid set to blobedit (bekmemo). Recreating columns switches that field to normal text field.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question. You don't want to delete columns from view, you just want to hide them? If that is the case, you can remove active view from grid using **cxGrid1.ActiveLevel.GridView := nil;** and later assign right view when you want columns to appear.

Comment: cxGrid1.ActiveLevel.GridView := nil;  works better...thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to create another cxgridlevel > cxGrid1dbtableview. Then just call set this level on form show:

```
procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
cxGrid1.ActiveLevel.GridView := cxGrid1DBTableView3;
end;
```

Since it is assigned to nothing so will the grid display empty.